# Is this an acceptable way of managing resources?

Tags: c++, memory-management

To manage various resources in my game (fonts bitmaps etc), I want to create managers which map strings to whatever resource. And this object, when out of scope, frees all memory used by the resources.

So basically if you want a Font, you'd either add it or request with a string indicating its name and it would return a pointer to it. This way the user never has to manage any memory.

Is this a good design for a small video game?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a the Factory Pattern combined with Smart Pointer/Scoped Pointer.

It is pretty reasonable. Just consider if you really need to use a string for identifying the resource. An enum might be enough.

Comment: Indeed, memory cleanup should be fast, string comparison is at best slow compared to enums.

Comment: That approach would be pretty reasonable, but it's not quite what's described.  It sounds like resources are only deallocated when the entire manager object is destroyed, not when the individual resource is no longer needed.  So the individual resources aren't managed in smart-pointer fashion.

Comment: @Wyzard Hmm, I guess it can be read both ways, but I though that OP meant that each resource would be deallocated when it got out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem here if your manager returns ordinary pointers - resources will hang around until the manager itself is destroyed (which is inefficient, particularly for resources like bitmaps), or until you make an explicit call to the manager to get rid of them, which may not happen if exceptions are thrown. It would be better for the manager to return smart pointers of some sort that can inform the manager when the resource is finished with.

Comment: +1 this reminds me of a "cache" implementation which would only fill up, right until the point where no memory at all was available. While not a memory leak (technically), it still means that memory consumption was totally unbound *ahem*...

Comment: @Matthieu It is also a common problems with custom memory allocators that "solve" memory leaks by hiding them. And of early LISP implementations, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds kind of like a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), if it automatically deallocates itself when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider a [boost::intrusive_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) so that all your objects are ref counted. You can then perform manual disposal of them from within the manager should you need to.

Of course you can write your own smart pointer classes, or you can just take it from someone who already has:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm